# How to get this subcollection's ref id in firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get this subcollection's ref id
[image]

I am following this tutorial however :
[2]: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/consume-data-from-firebase-firestore-in-a-react-app

I want to get the `hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryeTQZnHz2` from the firestore  :

```
 const HighlightDbId =  await db.collection('highlights')
  .doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk')
  .collection('hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryeTQZnHz2')
```

Please how can I possible get that id ??

Answer (score 0):

The code you currently have creates a reference to the collection.

Data won't be loaded from that reference until you call `get()` or `onSnapshot` on it, so:

```
 const HighlightDbId =  await db.collection('highlights')
  .doc('2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk')
  .collection('hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryeTQZnHz2')
  .get()
```

Comment: thank you , but how can I possibly get that second collection's id `hBYWvZ3KN3NLLrucTpryeTQZnHz2` only by using it doc's id `2SCS2S0JnzngWEiYkHNk` ?

Comment: Ah, I now get what you want: you want to get a list of the subcollections of a document through the API.

Comment: yes , actually what I want specifically is to get all the highlights data based on the first doc's id

Comment: An API to list subcollections only exists in the Admin/server-side SDKs. So if you *are* indeed using the SDK for Node, you can use the API in the answer I linked. If you're using the regular client-side JavaScript SDK, no API to list collections exists and you should consider using well-known collection names.